# Extern function gets wrong parameters assembly

Tags: assembly

Just want to create a procedure stored in another file. So I have file1.asm with main function(start point) and file2.asm that contains a procedure.

```
EXTRN MatrixTrack:FAR
.model flat, c
.386p
.stack 100h
.data
    matrix  dw 2, 3, 4, 5
            dw 4, 5, 2, 1
            dw 2, 6, 9, 8
            dw 3, 6, 3, 1
    matrix_dimension dw 4
    element_type dw 2
    result dw ?,"$"
.code
start:
;Assume data segment with ds, es
        push OFFSET result
        push element_type
        push matrix_dimension
        push OFFSET matrix
        call MatrixTrack
        add sp, 0Ah
;Exit operation
end start
END
```

Well, and in file2 I have the next:

```
PUBLIC MatrixTrack
LOCALS
.386p
.model flat, c
.code
MatrixTrack PROC C FAR USES ax bx cx si
    ARG @@matrix_address:word
    ARG @@matrix_dimension:word
    ARG @@element_length:word
    ARG @@result_storage_address:word
;here some operations
ENDP
END
```

Well when I push parameters to stack in file1 in data watch I see normal, real values, but when I debug the procedure the values are totally different. For example, `matrix_address` is 2Eh instead of 0Ah, `matrix_dimension` is 52FBh instead 4h, `element_length` is 208h instead of 2h, `result_storage_address` is 19Bh instead of 2Eh.

I'm a bit confused of bp offset created for values in lst file by assembler, maybe that matters:

```
@@ELEMENT_LENGTH          Number [FLAT:EBP+0010]
@@MATRIX_ADDRESS          Number [FLAT:EBP+000C]
@@MATRIX_DIMENSION        Number [FLAT:EBP+000E]
@@RESULT_STORAGE_ADDRESS      Number [FLAT:EBP+0012]
```

But what's wrong with theese addresses?

Comment: You seem to be mixing 16 and 32 bit code, decide which one you want. PS: rule of thumb is not to use clever assembler features unless you understand them fully. Especially for beginners it's best to write out things by hand.

Comment: @Jester, I'm sorry, but could tou tell me where I mixed 16 and 32 bit codes? or what i should do to find problem solution

Comment: The `.model flat` and the `.386p` hint that you are writing 32 bit code. But all the `word` stuff and the 16 bit registers hint that you are writing 16 bit code. You should decide what environment you are writing code for and change one or the other accordingly.

Comment: @Jester, I need to try .model small, .386 instead, don't I?

Comment: Could be. Are you trying to write 16 bit code then?

Comment: @Jester, yeah, i'll try a bit later